# steered wheel controller wheel joints not working

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-control, mobile-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use [steered wheel base controller](http://wiki.ros.org/steered_wheel_base_controller) for my four wheeled mobile base. I was trying to implement steering joints as position controlled and axle joints as velocity controlled.

My problem is, while publishing cmd_vel , axle joints are not working. Velocity command from ros control is always outputs as zero. But steering joints which uses position control is working when I published  yaw velocity.

Is it problem with velocity control I implemented or it is a problem with steered base controller ?

What all things I need to taken care while setting control frequency of controller manager?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204188/steered-wheel-controller-wheel-joints-not-working/) by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got solution. The mistake is I registered position and velocity hardware interfaces for each joints.

---

Originally posted by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) with karma: 233 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mos](https://answers.ros.org/users/22130/mos/) on 2015-08-28**:
So, it means we should not use position and velocity hardware interfaces,? Did you use this in Gazebo?
How did you define the transmissions in URDF for this controller?